# When providing a lambda for Runnable why I dont have to override run method?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, lambda, overriding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcDJy.jpg)

```
val obj = Runnable {
        for (i in 1..3)
        {
            println("$i")
            Thread.sleep(500)
        }
    }
    val r1 = Thread(obj)
    r1.start()
```

Comment: Can you include a minimal, reproducible, example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself (not in an image) ? That way people can try running it themselves and will be more able to help. Your code looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin has a feature called the [SAM(Single Abstract method) Conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html), which allows you to specify a `lambda` where a `SAM` interface is expected and the language takes care of creating the implementation for you. This makes sense because there is only one `method` in these interfaces (ie. Runnable), so why you should write all the boilerplate code, why not just provide the implementation of `SAM` as a `lambda`.

So in your example even though you dont `override` the `run` `method`, the code that you provide as `lambda` is actually `run` method's implementation. And in its complete form, it would look like this

```
val obj = object: Runnable{
    override fun run() {
        for (i in 1..3)
        {
            println("$i")
            Thread.sleep(500)
        }
    }
}
```